# instruction of replacement axiom

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I self-studied the book "Set Theory (Jech)", but I cannot understand the 22, 25 pages(attached below) during two months.

I guess 'replacement' of p.22 is used through these steps. (but I think it is wrong...)

(1) We know $a_i $ is set. (for arbitrary $i < \alpha$)

(2) $S = \{ (0,(0,a_0 ) ), (1, (1, a_1 ) ) , (2, (2, a_2 ) ), \cdots \}$ is class function. it is class because if I define

"$\phi (x) :$ there exist $i, j, k$ such that $x=(i, (i, j))$ and $i \in \alpha$ and $j = (< \; a_t \mid t<i \; >, k) $",

then $S = \{ x : \phi(x) \}$.

(3) So $S( \alpha) = \{ (0,a_0 ) ), (1, a_1 ) ) , (2, a_2 ), \cdots \}$ is set by replacement axiom. This is $\alpha$-sequence we wanted.

Is it right? I am not confidant.

And I don't have any idea regarding replacement of p.25.
I think when I saw extremely rigorous and formal proof if possible, I may realize the point.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Compare with other books, I think this is the best approach to understand something. If you read the same things but of different mathematicians you will be able in some moment to understand every point of view/approach to the same topic.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you recommand a set theory book has similar approach with Jech?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

I'll suggest you to compare Jech's proof with a "more detailed" one, like the one into:

- Herbert Enderton, [Elements of set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA175) (1977).

It may be useful to start from the **Recursion Theorem on $\omega$** [page 75]. The sought function $h$ is the union of a collection $\mathcal K$ of "approximating functions".

I order to assert the existence of $h$ the **Union Axiom** [page 24] is needed.

Consider now [page 177 and 180] the:

> *Proof of the Transfinite Recursion Theorem*. The proof is similar, in its 
>   general outline, to the proof of the recursion theorem on $\omega$. Again we 
>   construct the desired function $F$ as the union of many approximating functions.

But $Ord$ is not a set [see comment on *Replacement*, page 179] and thus the union is not licensed by the **Union Axiom**.

Thus:

> the set $\mathcal K$ of all functions [...] is provided by a replacement axiom [i.e. a suitable instance of the **Replacement Axiom schema**].